# HTML tags with spaces

Tags: html, tags, space

so I have a strange request. I've been working on some security project for school, and I've been able to successfully inject some html code using a form on our test site. What's interesting is that it only accepts the html code as one line and with no spaces. This brings me to my question, so far I've only been able to get text and font color changes to work. But I want to see if someone could inject images/audio/video.

I'm trying to figure out how to turn this:

```
<img src="http://www.rtur.net/blog/image.axd?picture=2011%2F12%2Fcss.png"/>
```

Into this:

```
<imgsrc="http://www.rtur.net/blog/image.axd?picture=2011%2F12%2Fcss.png"/>
```

but add a space with code.

I've tried adding the `&nbsp;` but that only works with actualy text and not the tag itself. Any help is appreciated.

Interesting note: I was able to inject `<font size="50" color="red"></font>`
But I have no idea why that works but the image doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

A slash:

```
<img\ src="http://www.rtur.net/blog/image.axd?picture=2011%2F12%2Fcss.png"/>
```

Using a non-traditional closing tag:

```
<img src="http://www.rtur.net/blog/image.axd?picture=2011%2F12%2Fcss.png"></img>
```

Injecting a blank `<img>` tag:

```
<img src=""/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution: Try inline CSS:

```
<div style="background:url(http://www.rtur.net/blog/image.axd?picture=2011%2F12%2Fcss.png);height:400px;width:400px"></div>
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9MYrM/

Comment: Also their CSS may be interfering with your injection.